# Noise in energy spectrum

Tags: plotting, numerics

I am plotting the Landau levels of a system numerically. Every thing is going right except a lot of noise in the energy spectrum. Please, help me out to resolve this issue. Thanks!

[image]

```
c = 3*10^8;
m = (0.09*5.1*10^5)/(c^2);
ℏ = 6.6*10^-16;
v = 4.7*10^5;
Δ = 0.24*10^-3*B;
Subscript[ω, 0] = ℏ*B*m^-1;
Subscript[ω, D] = Sqrt[2*ℏ*B*v^2];
ll = Sqrt[(2*B)/ℏ];

Block[{L = 20, Γ = 1.3*10^-3, λ = 2.5*10^-28, i,
   j, one, a, adag, wa, qd, H, Es, list, nn},
 one = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, {L, L}];
 a = SparseArray[{j_, i_} /; i - j == 1 -> Sqrt[j], {L, L}];
 adag = SparseArray[{j_, i_} /; j - i == 1 -> Sqrt[i], {L, L}];
 wa = ll^3*λ*(a . a . a + adag . adag . adag);
 qd = Subscript[ω, 0]*(adag . a);
 H[B_] = 
  ArrayFlatten[{{(Δ + 0.5*Subscript[ω, 0])*one + 
      qd + wa, 
     I*Subscript[ω, D]*a}, {-I*Subscript[ω, D]*
      adag, (-Δ + 0.5*Subscript[ω, 0])*one + qd -
       wa}}];
 list[B_?NumericQ] := list[B] = Eigenvalues[H[N[B]]];
 list[B_?NumericQ, nn_] := list[B][[nn]];
 Plot[Evaluate@Transpose@Table[list[B, nn], {nn, 2*L}], {B, 0, 40}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 40}, {-0.06, 0.1}}, ImageSize -> 500]
 ]
```

Comment: In the way that this is phrased, it does not seem to be a Mathematica question. Perhaps you should consider posing it in a different way!

Comment: @bbmf I believe it is in as much as it involves sorting the eigenvalues? May be use exclusion zone?

Comment: @chris all I meant was the simple: "help me translate the noise" or "help me clear our the noise" without a specific mathematics/physics task to be implemented into mathematica seems a question of understanding the background material better and not the software. This is why I said in the way it is phrased, not in its essence

Answer (score 7):

As suggested by @chris, the vertical lines are caused by the order of spectra.

Add `Sort` to this line

```
list[B_?NumericQ] := list[B] = Sort@Eigenvalues[H[N[B]]];
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the green blue and yellow line switch near (20,0).

Comment: @chris:  If you look carefully, the lines switch color whenever they intersect.  This is a side-effect of using `Sort` and it may or may not be acceptable for the OP.

Comment: (Though I have no idea how one would go about creating a "clean" plot in which they didn't swap like this)

Comment: Thanks for removing the noise. But the lines which are crossing are not straight. Could you please help me to resolve it.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I don't think it makes sense to talk about which eigenvalue belongs to which curve. Maybe we can try to keep the first derivative of the curve to be continuous, but there can also be cases the first derivatives of two curves are equal, or there can be singularities.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert For simple examples, say a 2 by 2 matrix, we can analyse the curves by solving the eigenvalues in closed form, and see how they depend on the extra parameters. But for higher-rank matrix, we get the spectral curve defined by $\det(M(a)-\lambda)=0$, where $a$ is the extra parameter. I think it's hard to analyse the structure of eigenvalues.

Comment: @user199 see my comments above.

Comment: For the intersecting eigenvalues, do you know from the context of the problem whether those are true intersections --  corresponding to degenerate eigenvalues -- or just small gaps -- corresponding to avoided crossings? If small gaps, smaller parameter steps could avoid the color change. If degeneracy, where all linear combinations of the two corresponding. eigenvectors have the same eigenvalues, what criterion do you want to connect eigenvalues from before and after the degeneracy?

Comment: tad, yes they are true intersections. I want to connect the asymmetry due to quadratic term in the Hamiltonian. Is there any solution to this problem? Please, share it.

Comment: @tad I'm not familiar with Landau levels:(. user199 has replied to you. Maybe you can discuss further.

Comment: @user199 Can you give a smaller example, e.g., with just two intersecting levels, to show how you want to match eigenvalues across the degeneracy. E.g., as Lacia suggests, would you want continuous derivatives of the curves at the degeneracy? At least for cases where slopes of the two curves are different. Do you have a more general criterion in mind that would also handle two curves with same slope at the degeneracy?

Comment: @tad, I don't have such kind of criteria. But the actual result should be free from avoided crossings and gaps between the curves. Is there any solution to avoid crossings and gaps?

Comment: You could order the set of values at each horizontal value to match with those from the previous set. Another possibility is to determine the eigenvectors and sort based on how well they match, e.g., using CosineDistance between the eigenvectors.